# Want to print array elements in .erb file in test kitchen in single line with one space

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

```
 /opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -N <%=@clust_name %>  -c -C cldb  -Z <%       @zookeeprall.each do |node| -%> 
    <%= node %>:<%=@zk_p %>
    <% end %>
```

zookeeperall is array and i want to print the array in single line but space between elements here it is printing new line

Comment: Can you edit your answer and paste the output of this code snippet?

Comment: /opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -N <%=@clust_name %>  -c -C   -Z <%=@zkall.join(":<%=@zk_p %> ") %>

Comment: i am running this but some syntax error  `/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -N <%=@clust_name %>  -c -C   -Z <%=@zkall.join(":<%=@zk_p %> ") %>`

Comment: Chef::Mixin::Template::TemplateError ((erubis):6: syntax error, unexpected '>'
       (erubis):11: unterminated string meets end of file) on line #:

Comment: Please use the `chef` tag in the future so we can find your question.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the whole thing on one line:

```
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -N <%=@clust_name %>  -c -C cldb  -Z <% @zookeeprall.each do |node| -%><%= node %>:<%=@zk_p %> <% end %>
```

You could also use a Ruby expression like:

```
/opt/mapr/server/configure.sh -N <%=@clust_name %>  -c -C cldb  -Z <%= @zookeeprall.map {|node| "#{node}:#{@zk_p}" }.join(' ') %>
```